# Hymns are from Athervana Veda Paippalāda Shakha on Rudra/Shiva. Seeking meaning full translation and Sandhi

Tags: vedas, shiva, rudra

Following Hymns are towards Rudra from Atharvana Veda Paippalāda Shakha 14 Kanda, 3rd and 4th Sukta.
There is no translation available yet. Some universities are working towards them as this Shakha palm leaf manuscripts were recently uncovered in Odisha. Can someone kingly provider a meaningful Sandhi (word-break down) and translation in English if possible? Little attempt has been made, yet the experts' perspective is very valuable. Interestingly the 5th hymn has both terms 'Girisha' and 'Shiva'. Thank you in advance.

दिव उग्रो ऽवारुक्षत् प्रत्यष्ठाद् भूभ्यामधि । जनासः पश्यतेमं नीलग्रीवं विलोहितम् ।।२।।
Oh fierce divine who came down from the skys and appeared on Earth.
All beings/people witnessed the one with blue throath, and redish hue.

एष ऐत्यवीरहा रुद्रो जलापभेषजी । वि ते क्षेपमनीनशद्वातीकारो व्येतु ते ।।३।।
there come our Hero (ऐत्य-वीरहा) Rudra(रुद्रो ) with your liquid medicens (जलाप-भेषजी) ...

नमस्ते भव भामाय नमस्ते भव मन्यवे । नमस्ते अस्तु बाहुभ्यामुतो त इषवे नमः ।।४।।
Salutations (नमस्ते) to thy Bhava-The lord of creation (भव), of fierce wrath (भामाय ),
of great energy/fire (मन्यु), Salutions to the one with mighty shoulders (बाहुभ्य) and to sole lord/ruler/authority (इषवे) I salute to thy (नमः).

यामिषु गिरिशन्त हस्ते बिभर्फास्तवे । शिवां गिरिश तां कृणु मा हिंसीः पुरुषान् मम ।।५।।

शिवेन वचसा त्वा गिरिशाच्छा वदामसि । यथा नः सर्वमिज्जगदयक्ष्मं सुमनो असत् ।।६।।
या त इषुः शिवतमा शिवं बभूव ते धनुः । शिवा शरव्या या तव तया नो मृड जीवसे ।।७।।
या ते रुद्र शिवा तनूरघोरापापकाशिनी । तया नस्तन्वा शन्तमया गिरिशन्ताभि चाकश ।।८।।
असौ यस्तानो अरुण उत बभ्रुर्विलोहित । ये चेमे अभितो रुद्रा दिक्ष श्रिता:सहस्रशोऽवैषां हेड़ ईमहे।।९।।
अदृशन् त्वावरोहन्तं नीलग्रीवं विलोहितम् । उत त्वा गोपा अदृशन्नुत त्वोदहार्यः । उतो त्वा विश्वा भूतानि तस्मै दृष्टाय ते नमः।।१०।।
१४-४  (14-4)
नमो ऽस्तु नीलशिखण्डाय सहस्राक्षाय वाजिने । अथो ये अस्य सत्वानस्तेभ्यो ऽहमकरं नमः ।।१।।
नमांसि त आयुधायानातताय धृष्णवे । उभाभ्यामकरं नमो बाहुभ्यां तव धन्वने ।।२।।
प्र मुञ्च धन्वनस्पर्युभयोरायॊाम् । याच ते हस्त इषवः परा ता भगवो वप ।।३।।
अवतत्य धनुस्त्वं सहस्राक्ष शतेषुधे । निशीर्य शल्यानां मुखा शिवो नः शम्भुरा भव ।।४।।
विज्यं धनुः शिखण्डिनो विशल्यो वणवाङ उत । अनेशन्नस्येषवः शिवो अस्य निषङ्गतिः ।।५।।
परि ते धन्वनो हेतिरस्मान् वृणक्तु विश्वतः । अथो य इषुधिस्तवारे अस्मन्नि धेहि तम् ।।६।।
या ते हेतिर्मिढुष्टम हस्ते बभूव ते धनुः । तया त्वं विश्वतो अस्मनयक्ष्मया परि भुज ।।७।।

PS. Tagging @Tezz ji

Comment: Why is यॊ in the mantra this is an English addition to hindi, you might want to look into the typo